# ActiveStorage: Ordering ActiveRecord Models by attachment Filename (ERROR missing FROM-clause entry for table "active_storage_blobs")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am building a Rails app with a webpage that shows a list of QuoteDocuments sorted by the quotedocument's PDF created date, which is attached via ActiveStorage

```
class Quote < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :quote_documents, dependent: :destroy
end
class QuoteDocument < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :document
end
```

This is the line of code I am using that gives me an error

```
@quote.quote_documents.includes(:document_attachment).order('active_storage_blobs.filename ASC')
```

And this is the error

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "active_storage_blobs")`

And the SQL statement

`: SELECT  "quote_documents"."id" AS t0_r0, "quote_documents"."quote_id" AS t0_r1, "quote_documents"."version" AS t0_r2, "quote_documents"."created_at" AS t0_r3, "quote_documents"."updated_at" AS t0_r4, "quote_documents"."document_file_name" AS t0_r5, "quote_documents"."document_content_type" AS t0_r6, "quote_documents"."document_file_size" AS t0_r7, "quote_documents"."document_updated_at" AS t0_r8, "quote_documents"."document_type" AS t0_r9, "quote_documents"."description" AS t0_r10, "quote_documents"."user_id" AS t0_r11, "active_storage_attachments"."id" AS t1_r0, "active_storage_attachments"."name" AS t1_r1, "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" AS t1_r2, "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" AS t1_r3, "active_storage_attachments"."blob_id" AS t1_r4, "active_storage_attachments"."created_at" AS t1_r5 FROM "quote_documents" LEFT OUTER JOIN "active_storage_attachments" ON "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = "quote_documents"."id" AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $2 WHERE "quote_documents"."quote_id" = $3 AND "quote_documents"."document_type" = $4 ORDER BY active_storage_blobs.filename ASC LIMIT $5`

Any idea what I should be doing to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use include in your original statement that sets the `@quote`, rather than from the `@quote` variable:

```
@quote = Quote.includes(quote_documents: {document_attachment: :blob}).find(params[id])
```

in your controller

then in your view you should just be able to use:

```
@quote.quote_documents.order('active_storage_blobs.filename ASC')
```

Comment: Gave this a try in rails console,  I get the following error `ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError (Association named 'document_attachment' was not found on Quote; perhaps you misspelled it?)`

Comment: I updated OP. `document_attachment` is attached to the `Quote` via a `has_many` association to `QuoteDocument`

Comment: sorry, code updated in place with the new info.  you might need to duplicate the 'includes' as 'joins' in order for it to allow the ordering, but YMMV